# When does $\mathbb{E}\left[h(X, Y) \, \vert \, X = x \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[h(x,Y) \, \vert \, X = x \right]$ hold?

Tags: measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X, Y$ be random variables with values in $\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Y}$ and $h \colon \mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{Y} \to \mathbb{R}$ be measurable, integrable and whatever.

I want to know if we have a reasonable equality (that means in an almost sure sense)
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[h(X, Y) \, \vert \, X = x \right]
= \mathbb{E}\left[h(x,Y) \, \vert \, X = x \right].
$$

I convinced myself that this is true in the case where we can disintegrate the joint distribution of $X, Y$.

Is this identity true in a more general situation?

Comment: One needs to be careful with definitions here, since conditioning on $X=x$ is not really defined in general. Instead, one should use the measure theoretic definition of conditional expectation given the random variable $X$. With the natural definitions, you can see that this holds by a standard monotone class argument, using the fact that it is clear for product form functions and that product-form sets generate the product sigma algebra.

Comment: The first part was clear (in the case where $X = x$ has nonzero probability the statement is trivial). Thanks for the second part though, I can take it from there!